# how to insert array data to array multidimension at the end in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have array multi dimension from looping *foreach*.
I want to insert new data from array at the end of array multi dimension like this :

```
Array
   (
     [setting_code] => gen_logo
     [setting_value] => logo.png
   )


Array
   (
[0] => Array
    (
        [setting_code] => gen_site_name
        [setting_value] => Codeigniter School CMS
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [setting_code] => gen_email_info
        [setting_value] => info@schoolapp.sch
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [setting_code] => gen_meta_author
        [setting_value] => awnLabs.co
    )
  )
```

then the result I want like this :

```
Array
   (
[0] => Array
    (
        [setting_code] => gen_site_name
        [setting_value] => Codeigniter School CMS
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [setting_code] => gen_email_info
        [setting_value] => info@schoolapp.sch
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [setting_code] => gen_meta_author
        [setting_value] => awnLabs.co
    )
[3] =>Array
   (
     [setting_code] => gen_logo
     [setting_value] => logo.png
   )
  )
```

how to get result like the above? thank's for help before :)

Comment: Have you considered `$arr[] = `, or `array_push`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply can assign using `$arr2[] = $arr1` or [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php). Example:

```
$arr1 = Array
(
    "setting_code" => "gen_logo",
    "setting_value" => "logo.png",
);


$arr2 = array
(
    0 => array
    (
        "setting_code" => "gen_site_name",
        "setting_value" => "Codeigniter School CMS"
    ),
    1 => array
    (
        "setting_code" => "gen_email_info",
        "setting_value" => "info@schoolapp.sch"
    ),
    2 => array
    (
        "setting_code" => "gen_meta_author",
        "setting_value" => "awnLabs.co",
    )
);

$arr2[] = $arr1;
// or 
//array_push($arr2, $arr1);

print "<pre>";
print_r($arr2);
print "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to insert data at the end of array.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)function.

Here is the example:

```
    $arr1 =
            Array
            (
            "setting_code" => "gen_logo",
             "setting_value" => "logo.png",
            );
    $arr2 = 
            Array
            (
            Array
                (
                    "setting_code" => "gen_site_name",
                "setting_value" => "Codeigniter School CMS"
            ),
            //Rest elements

            );
   $result = array_merge($arr2, $arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

array_push is simple and easy to for this situation. For example:

```
    $logo_1 = array
       (
         'setting_code' => 'gen_logo',
         'setting_value' => 'logo.png'
       );
    $logo_2 = array
           (
             'setting_code' => 'gen_logo',
             'setting_value' => 'logo.png'
           );
   $arr = array();
   array_push($arr, $logo_1);
   array_push($arr, $logo_2);
   var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var=array();
$test_arr['setting_code']='gen_site_name';
$test_arr['setting_value']='Codeigniter School CMS';
array_push($var, $test_arr);
$test_arr['setting_code']='gen_email_info';
$test_arr['setting_value']='info@schoolapp.sch';
array_push($var, $test_arr);
$test_arr['setting_code']='gen_meta_author';
$test_arr['setting_value']='awnLabs.co';
array_push($var, $test_arr);
foreach ($var as $key=>$value){
    $arr[$key]=$value;
}
```

By using this code you will get the output you need, a small example of array_push

Thanks